# Kubernetes DNS Service Name Stability

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using a feature in nginx that requires specifying a resolver, otherwise I would just rely on the `resolve.conf` host resolver configuration provided by kubernetes.

What I'm wondering is if the service name `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local` would be considered by the kubernetes project to be stable for backcompat purposes so that I can rely on it to not disappear in minor releases.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name "~^(?<host_name>host-[0-9a-z]{7,10}).domain.tld$";

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my.key;

    # Use a variable here to force nginx to respect DNS ttl and reresolve
    # See: https://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/
    resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;
    set $downstream_api http://hostapi.default.svc.cluster.local:3000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          $downstream_api;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suffix piece (`cluster.local`) is configurable cluster to cluster, but I think you can feel confident that the dns will be consistent throughout releases. It did change very early on, but hasn't since.